# Cypher: Query that converts property from int to String is very slow and causes OutOfMemoryError in Neo4j server

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I need to migrate the type of a numerical property to be of type String.
For that I wrote the simple following query:

```
MATCH (n:Entity) SET n.id=toString(n.id) RETURN n
```

It matches about 1,2 million entities (according to EXPLAIN), so I didn't expect it to be fast. However, it didn't terminate after more than 5 hours. In the meantime neo4j server (community, 3.0.4) ran at close to 100% load.

I have this configured in the corresponding neo4j.conf:

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=4g
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=4g
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+UseG1GC
```

After only a few minute of runtime, I could see reports about GarbageCollection in the logs:

```
[o.n.k.i.c.MonitorGc] GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for 277ms.
```

later it got worse:

```
[o.n.k.i.c.MonitorGc] GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for 53899ms.
```

Eventually the following appeared:

```
 [o.n.b.v.r.i.c.SessionWorker] Worker for session '10774fef-eed2-4593-9a20-732d9103e576' crashed: Java heap space Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[o.n.b.v.r.i.c.SessionWorker] Fatal, worker for session '10774fef-eed2-4593-9a20-732d9103e576' crashed. Please contact your support representative if you are unable to resolve this. Java heap space java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

The total available heap should suffice from my previous experience as I have run way "heavier" queries before without problems.
I rather assume that the query is cause for the poor performance. However I don't see how to improve it.
Actually the migration doesn't have to happen in one query or transaction. To my knowledge it is not possible though to "batch" it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For one, I don't think you need to return the entire 1.2 million set of nodes, you can leave off your return.

And yes, you can batch these using [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/). In particular you'll want to look at [apoc.periodic.iterate()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_iterate) and [apoc.periodic.commit()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_commit).

Here's how you might batch this with apoc.periodic.iterate():

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"MATCH (n:Entity) RETURN n",
"WITH {n} as n SET n.id=toString(n.id)", {batchSize:10000, parallel:true})
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! Runtime with that configuration was 1 1/2 minutes. Pretty good improvement :)